# Join Remote database table with my Local database table in SQL Server 2012

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I am using SQL Server 2012 Management Studio. I tried to connect to a remote database. I was able to connect successfully but i was restricted to access only for four views. I tried the following steps to join the table with my local table.

1. I tried to use linkedserver but I was un-able to add the remote server due to permission restriction so i was un-able to modify the `SP_LinkedServer`.
2. I tried to copy the table but i was un-able to copy it to my local database.

I am planning to compare my local table with my remote table. I am new to SQL Server, curious to learn. Please correct me if have a wrong understanding.

I appreciate your kind help

Comment: I assume the remote DB is also a MS-SQL Server? Get the right permissions for linked server. It's the best solution for cross-server queries.

Comment: Hi Martin, Thank you for the quick response. Yes both are MS SQL server. I am not sure whether i will be provided with the access. Is there any other solution to fix this. May be any way to copy the data. I am not sure whether i have a proper understanding. Please correct me if i'm wrong. Thanks

Comment: I would have to agree with @Martin..If you are planning on running cross server queries then set them up as linked servers.

Comment: oh ok. Thank you Dev N00B. Not sure about the access restriction.

Comment: ask the DBA to do it, i would be surprised if they weren't already you may just have permission restriction to certain things, also you may find a problem running linked server queries from a local machine as they may be set up as one hop linked. Unfortunately its not the answer you want to hear but feel it is probably the best solution especially going forward

Comment: oh ok. Thank you Dev N00B. I will check with the DBA.

Comment: Just to learn. Is there any possible way to copy it to my Temp table?

Answer (score 0):

You should try using the SQL Server Import and Export Wizard:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms140052.aspx

If possible you could export the data from one server and import it to the other using the wizard.

If this is not possible then you could export to a file from one server, and then import from a file onto the other.

Comment: Thank you. Petio Ivanov. I will try with SQL Server Import and Export Wizard.