# How to do a join between tables in test environment and development environment in sql server?

Tags: sql-server-2008

I'm trying to join table "A" in test environment with table "A" in development environment to check if there are any differences ?

Is there a way to join the tables between different environments or is there a procedure for what i'm trying to accomplish ?

I do not work with multiple environments simultaneously and I have no idea how to do this.

Answer (score 0):

IMHO you'd be better off e.g. exporting the table "A" from dev and loading it in "test" (either in A, with some sort of script, or in a A_dev and then perform the join locally).

Alternatively, you could do a script to connect to both DBs and compare the tables programatically. Alternatively, you could try a store procedure in the test DB to connect to the dev DB. I haven't ever tried this, but [according to this article](http://database.ittoolbox.com/documents/connecting-to-and-accessing-a-sql-server-database-on-another-server-18751) it might work.

Alternatively, you should try the import/export wizard as per [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17701273/join-remote-database-table-with-my-local-database-table-in-sql-server-2012).

Comment: I don't have anything handy here, but I think this is usable: http://www.fryan0911.com/2009/06/vbnet-how-to-select-records-from-sql.html

Comment: I have been exporting the contents of table "A" from dev and exporting it to test locally. I'm more interested in your comment, "Alternatively, you could do a script to connect to both DBs and compare the tables programatically", do you have an example ?